# Is there a process in Excel that can automate reading through a column containing TRUE/FALSE values and can add numbers incrementally in a new column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

I have a very large spreadsheet containing over 50,000 rows. They are records of events from a camera trap. I have a column called "NewEvent" which contains only TRUE or FALSE values, which was based on whether the camera trap was triggered as a new event. However now I need to number the events in the order that they happened and record these values in a new column. For example, the very first TRUE would be marked as event 1 in the new column, and all FALSE values following it would also still be part of event 1, until there is another TRUE which would then be event 2 and so on. I started doing this manually but realized it will take me a considerable amount of time. Is there any way to automate this using VBA or macro etc in Excel? Please see the example below:

| NewEvent | EventNum |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | 1 |
| FALSE | 1 |
| FALSE | 1 |
| FALSE | 1 |
| TRUE | 2 |
| FALSE | 2 |
| FALSE | 2 |
| TRUE | 3 |
| FALSE | 3 |
| FALSE | 3 |
| FALSE | 3 |
| FALSE | 3 |

I tried experimenting with the code editor in Macro but I am very new to this and found it a little complex for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Quite possible with formula try this: `=SCAN(0,N(--A2:A13),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,x)))` it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: This thread turned into a bit of Code Golf. The shortest answer appears to be:

```
=N(B1)+A2
```

[image]

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Using `COUNTIFS` with a mixed range reference. May bog down the worksheet if you have tens of thousands of rows!

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Another (more performant) option:

```
=IF(A2,SUM(B1,1),B1)
```

[image]

Yet another option (credit to [Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya))

```
=IF(A2,N(B1)+1,B1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Other than the solution provided by **[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben)** Sir, you can use <kbd>SCAN( )</kbd> to spill.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=SCAN(0,--A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,x)))
```

---

Edit: For the Spill Array!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=SCAN(0,--A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,(y+N(x))))
```

---

Another alternative approach. Without <kbd>IF( )</kbd> and using only <kbd>N( )</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=N(A2)+N(B1)
```

---

OfCourse the formula needs to fill down!!

---

The above formula can be made more shorter as proposed by @BigBen Sir.

```
=A2+N(B1)
```

---

[image]

---

A mandatory caveat : Formulas shown above all assumes, that the range starts with `TRUE`, if it isn't then one could use as below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=(A2+N(B1))+1
```

---

Answer (score 3):

For fun:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--A2:x)))
```

Or, with `SCAN()`:

```
=SCAN(0,A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this old-fashioned trick:

Imagine you have your "TRUE"/"FALSE" values in column "A" and you want your counter in column "B", then you start column "B" with 1 (as you always start with a TRUE"), and the following cell in column "B" gets following formula:

```
=IF(A2=TRUE,B1+1,B1)
```

This checks the value in the "A" column. In case of TRUE, an increase (`B1+1`) is done, otherwise the normal value (`B1`) is used.

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Side note, you can simplify `A2=TRUE` to just `A2`. But yeah, this is pretty similar to several of the options already proposed.

Comment: @BigBen: I'm sorry, I had only seen your `CountIFS` solution, I didn't realise your answer contained multiple solutions.

Comment: No need to apologize! You propose a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: Wow!! I went away for a couple of hours and came back to this brilliant discussion! Thank you so so much!! These are awesome and much simpler than I had imagined. I believed I had to use some complex macro to do this, so this is brilliant and I can start using it straight away. You are all awesome thank you!!